# Are principal component analysis (PCA) and empirical orthogonal function (EOF) methods the same?

Tags: time-series, pca, matrix-decomposition

As far as I've seen, EOF is just PCA but instead of thinking about the data matrix X as (number of samples, number of features), you consider it as (number of time points, number of different spatial positions).

Am I correct? Is the difference only conceptual?

I'm a bit confused because I've seen python packages specifically designed for EOF, which increases the confusion.

Thanks